# Find the length as a function of $r_1,r_2$

Tags: geometry

> We are given two mutually tangent circles in the plane, with radii $r_1,r_2$. A line intersects these circles in four points, determining three segments of equal length. Find this length as a function of $r_1$ and $r_2$ and the condition for the solvability of the problem.

The solution to this question is below. What I don't get is what the solution means by "Thus each of the equations in ($1$) has two roots, one of which is thrice the other." Firstly what equations are they talking about? I suspect that this might be a typo and they are referring to the top two equations. Also how do they get that each of the equations has two roots one of which is thrice the other from the fact that $x=y=d/2$?
[image]

Comment: The solution to the problem is actually incorrect, because it assumes that the circles are externally, rather than internally, tangent.

Comment: @David It could be either, right? Other than that in the case that it is externally tangent can you explain their reasoning?

Comment: Actually, I don't know whether either is possible in this case, where all three lengths are equal. But they certainly don't prove that it's impossible for the circles to be tangent internally. I'm looking at the case they do deal with.

Comment: @user19405892 So exact $r1/r2$ need not be known for line trisection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're referring not to the equations in $(1)$, but to the quadratic equations in the line above $(1)$. That's a slight error.

Let $A$ be the point of intersection of line $p$ with the $y$-axis. Once they have that $x = y = d/2$, it means that the distances from $A$ to the two points of intersection of $p$ with either circle must be $d/2$ and $3d/2$. It follows that the $x$-coordinates of the points are $\pm d_1/2$ and $\pm 3d_1/2$ (where $d_1$ is defined as in the text). The numbers $d_1/2$ and $3d_1/2$ are therefore the roots of the quadratic equation on the right, and $-d_1/2, -3d_1/2$ are the roots of the one on the left.

By the way, $-1$ to the author for using the word *thrice*.

Comment: Also any idea how they are getting the middle equations such as $ab = \dfrac{r_2-r_1}{2}$?

Comment: When you set the second and third members of (1) equal, you get $(ab + r_1)^2 = (ab - r_2)^2$. Since $ab + r_1 \ne ab - r_2$, it follows that $ab + r_1 = r_2 - ab$.

Comment: How did they get $(ab+r_1)^2 = 4(1+a^2)b^2/3$?

Comment: That's from relating the coefficients of a quadratic equation with roots $e$ and $3e$. If $\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma \equiv \alpha (x-e)(x - 3e)$, then by eliminating $e$ you obtain a relation between $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail I still don't see it.

Comment: If the equation $\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma = 0$ has the roots $e$ and $3e$, then $\beta = - 4\alpha e$ and $\gamma = 3\alpha e^2$. Therefore $16 \alpha \gamma = 3 \beta^2$.

Comment: Right, I get that. Can you lastly explain how they get $(1)$? Also the case of internally tangent I think is impossible.

Comment: I don't know about the case of internally tangent circles. I don't see an obvious reason it would be impossible. In the present case, the length $d_1$ is the difference between the roots of either of the two quadratic equations. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the two roots of an equation $\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma = 0$, then $(x_2 - x_1)^2 = (x_1 + x_2)^2 - 4x_1 x_2 = (-\beta/\alpha)^2 - 4\gamma/\alpha$.

Comment: The solution is written sort of funny. It says each of the quadratics have two roots but quadratics always have two roots (real or complex).

Comment: Here they must both be real.

Comment: But it is a trivial fact that both must be real here, right? It doesn't follow from $x = y = d/2$ that they must be real but from the question.

Comment: I am fairly sure the equal segments is impossible if they are internally tangent. It would violate the question as well.

Comment: Yes, it follows from the question that both roots are real. That is what they're saying. The line has two points of intersection with each circle.